# Excel: Toggle text color between two cells based on each cells value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I want to toggle text color between two cells based on each cell's value:
When the value in Cell 2 = 0, I want the font color in cell 1 to be black and the font color in Cell 2 to be gray.
When the value in Cell 2 > 0, I want the font color in cell 1 to be gray and the font color in Cell 2 to be black.

Cell 1 has a formula referencing values from another spreadsheet. Cell 2 has a keyboard inserted value.

I'm guessing that this will probably use Conditional Formatting.

Thank you!

I tried Conditional Formatting using a variety of options but came up empty. I know I'm missing something but I can't figure it out. I can change text color in each cell independently but not based on a relationship between the two cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to create four separate conditional formatting rules with the following formulae:

| Formula | Format | Applies to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `=$B$1=0` | Gray | `=$B$1` |
| `=$B$1=0` | Black | `=$A$1` |
| `=$B$1>0` | Black | `=$B$1` |
| `=$B$1>0` | Gray | `=$A$1` |

[image: The above table as an Excel screenshot.]

The first two formulae set the font color in cell 1 (`$A$1`) to black and the font color in cell 2 (`$B$1`) to gray when cell 2 equals `0`. The next two set the color of both cells when cell 2 is greater than `0`.

Examples:

[image: An Excel screenshot with a black-colored 6 in cell A1 and a gray-colored 0 in cell B1.]

*B1 equals 0*

[image: An Excel screenshot with a gray-colored 3 in cell A1 and a black-colored 5 in cell B1.]

*B1 is greater than 0*

Comment: Glad to hear it @user300246. If you'd like, please click the gray check mark in the top left of my answer to mark it as "accepted" for other users to see.